# Python kivy event processing

Tags: python, api, loops, kivy, cycle

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen, MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from skpy import SkypeEventLoop
from skpy import SkypeEvent
from skpy import SkypeNewMessageEvent
from skpy import SkypeCallMsg
from skpy import Skype
import subprocess

from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDSwitch
import random

class SkypeRecordApp(MDApp):

        def func(self, dt):
               
            class MySkype(SkypeEventLoop):

                  def onEvent(self, event):
                      print('Проверка...')
        
                      try:
                         print(event.msg.content)
                         if event.type == 'NewMessage':
                
                             print(event.msg.content)
                             check_for_call = event.msg.content[:6]
                         if check_for_call == """{"cp":""":
                             print("Входящий звонок")
                      except:
                            pass
            
           
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                  sk = MySkype("email", 'password', autoAck=True)
                  sk.subscribePresence() # Only if you need contact presence events.
                  sk.loop()
                  #problem here






                            
                
                
                        
        def click(self, switch, value):
                
                if (value):
                        
                        
                        
                        self.www = Clock.schedule_interval(self.func, 1)

                        
                            
                        
                else:
                        print('off')
                        self.www.cancel()
                        
                        
                        
                        
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                super().__init__(**kwargs)

                Window.clearcolor = (100, 100, 100, 100)
        
                self.window = MDBoxLayout(opacity=0, md_bg_color=[.2, .68, .93, 1], orientation='vertical')
                
                

                anim = Animation()
                anim = Animation(opacity=1)
                
                anim.start(self.window)

                
        
        def build(self):
                self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
                Window.size = (450, 600)
                
                logo_screen = MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
                logo_image = Image(source='skype.png',pos_hint={"center_x":.3, "center_y":.19})
                logo_screen.add_widget(logo_image)
                
                
                
                logo_screen.add_widget(Label(text="Skyper", font_name="Segoe UI Bold.ttf", font_size=58, pos_hint={"center_x":.3, "center_y":.1}))

                             
                self.window.add_widget(logo_screen)
                switch = MDSwitch(pos_hint={"center_x":.28, "center_y":.1}, track_color_active="white", on_active=self.click)
                self.window.add_widget(switch)
                switch.bind(active=self.click)
                rec = Label(text="Record", font_size=28, pos_hint={"center_x":.3, "center_y":.1}, size_hint_y=None)
                self.window.add_widget(rec)
                
                self.window.add_widget(BoxLayout(orientation="vertical"))
                return self.window

        
                

SkypeRecordApp().run()
```

I trying to get events of SkPy with kivymd MDSwitch (when is active), but im already create python kivy loop with
`self.www = Clock.schedule_interval(self.func, 1)`

problem in because is that loop, Python kivy app stopping when this work, I know about cycles in kivy (can't use in kivy), but how I can do this?

`sk.loop()`

How I can get events of SkPy in Python kivy?

Comment: is the code as shown in your Question the exact match of the code on your screen?  the indentation levels are all correct?  in general async things can be done fairly easily with Threads
threading.Thread(target=sk.loop, daemon=True).start()    but you will need more changes than just that.

Comment: Yes, same code, but which ones?

Comment: Thank you so much, I did that, just calling self.x = threading.Thread(target=self.func, daemon=True, args=(1,)) self.x.start()

Comment: Can't kill the thread on switch off, can you help me?